What does doubling negative money do?
In Balatro, the Credit Card Joker's effect says

Go up to -$20 in debt

The Hermit Tarot Card has the effect:

Doubles money (Max of $20)

What happens if you use a Hermit Tarot Card to double your money while you have negative money from the Credit Card?

Alternate title: What happens if I double my money while in Credit Card debt?

Good news: -$20 dollars of debt isn't negative money.

Using Hermit to double your money while you have negative money has no effect. It will not increase or decrease your debt.
Source: I tried it myself and recorded a video.



